# Does $y=9$ solve $2y+9(y-4)=52$?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

What are the steps to properly solve this?

Determine whether $y=9$ is the solution to the equation

$2y+9(y-4)=52$.

Comment:  no again :-) another recent linear (1st degree) equation $2y+9y-36=52\to 11y=56+32\to y=8$.

Comment: Thank you!!!!! :-)

Comment: You can see this beautiful book in English language: https://amsi.org.au/teacher_modules/pdfs/Linear_equations.pdf

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Is a solution to" means the same thing as "Makes the given things true". So to check whether $y = 9$ is a solution to $2y+9(y-4)=52$, we want to see whether choosing $y = 9$ makes that equation true.

The right-hand side of the equation is a nice simple constant, so we can leave it as it is. The left-hand side involves $y$, so let's plug our chosen value in:

$\begin{eqnarray}2y + 9(y - 4) & = & 2 \times 9 + 9(9 - 4) \mbox{ by substitution} \\
& = & 18 + 9 \times 5 \\
& = & 18 + 45 \\
& = & 63 \end{eqnarray}$

And so we ask, is $63 = 52$? No, the statement is clearly false, and so $y = 9$ is *not* a solution to the given equation.

As shown in the comments, the true solution is in fact $y = 8$, which you can find through standard solution methods, but it's useful to remember that you can test solutions like this because (a) it lets you prove that the answer you found was right, and (b) when solving more complicated equations you can sometimes accidentally introduce additional, incorrect solutions and you need to eliminate them. For example, you might accidentally introduce a division by zero, or take a square root of a negative number, or any of the many ways that show up in various [proofs that 1=0 or something](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_fallacy).